# Package document for methods from roxygen

Tags: r, methods, roxygen2

I created a regression model named polygonal linear regression. The correspondent function is `plr` and return an object of the class `plr`. To show the the summary of model I created a function summary (`summary.plr`). This function returns an object of the class `summary.plr`. Besides, I create a third function to print `summary.plr` objects named `print.summary.plr`. How can I document the method `print.summary.plr` using `roxygen2` and export the method for others functions in the package?

I tried this way:

```
#' Print Summary Polygonal Linear Regression
#'
#' @description print arguments of the class "\emph{summary.plr}" and returns it \emph{invisibly} (via \code{\link[base]{invisible}} (x)).
#' @method print summary.plr
#' @param x an object of the class "\emph{summary.plr}".
#' @param digits  non-null value for \code{digits} specifies the minimum number of significant 
#' digits to be printed in values.
#' @param concise a \emph{logical} used to determine the type of digits.
#' @export

#Outuput

Description

print arguments of the class "summary.plr" and returns it invisibly (via invisible (x)).

Usage

## S3 method for class 'summary.plr'
print(x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") -
  3L), concise = FALSE, ...)
Arguments

x an object of the class "summary.plr".
digits non-null value for digits specifies the minimum number of significant digits to be printed in values.
concise a logical used to determine the type of digits.
```

But I don't know if this is the correct way.

Comment: "I tried this way" ...and what was the result?

Comment: Ah, I see, you're just looking for confirmation that what you've done is correct. It is (it's basically how I've done it, and mostly comports with the approach in the [`tibble`](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blob/master/R/utils-format.r) package as well), though with a reasonably recent version of `roxygen2`, I'll say that I don't think you actually don't even need the `#' @method print summary.plr` line